# Is there a maximum size a DataGridView can be?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` inside a `Panel` so I can have smooth scrolling.

The DataGridView has it's height set to the total height of it rows.

I have a CellContentClick event on the DGV that only reacts when the e.ColumnIndex == 0.

At the moment I'm loading about 1700 rows. After about row 1489 which is at a height of about 32569px, this is the last row that I am able to click on the event fires.

**[EDIT]** 02 May 2017 9:59PM AU
Adding code to show what is happening. To the form I add a custom panel (code below) with AutoScroll set to true and then place a DataGridView with scrollbars set to none.

**Panel Class**

```
    public class CustomPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    {
        protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control activeControl)
        {
            // Returning the current location prevents the panel from scrolling to the active control when the panel loses and regains focus
            return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
        }
    }
```

**Data Class**

```
    public class dgvRecord
    {
        public double ID { get; set; }
        public string TYPE { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public DateTime DATE { get; set; }
        public dgvRecord() { }
    }
```

**Form Class**

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dgvInPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<dgvRecord> recList = new List<dgvRecord>();
        int normalRowHeight = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int rCount = 0; rCount < 1800; rCount++)
            {
                dgvRecord rec = new dgvRecord() { ID = 20170501000000, TYPE = "Asset", NAME = "Joe Bloggs", DATE = new DateTime(2017, 05, 02, 10, 30, 15) };
                recList.Add(rec);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle imageCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            imageCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
            imageCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dgv.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
            imageCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            DataGridViewCellStyle otherCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            otherCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft;

            dgv.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dgv.ReadOnly = true;

            DataGridViewCell dgvc_ID = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvTbxCol_ID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dgvc_ID,
                Name = "ID",
                HeaderText = "ID",
                DataPropertyName = "ID",
                DefaultCellStyle = otherCellStyle,
            };
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvTbxCol_ID);

            DataGridViewCell dgvc_TYPE = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvTbxCol_TYPE = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dgvc_TYPE,
                Name = "TYPE",
                HeaderText = "Type",
                DataPropertyName = "TYPE",
                AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells,
                DefaultCellStyle = otherCellStyle,
            };
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvTbxCol_TYPE);

            DataGridViewCell dgvc_R_NAME = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvTbxCol_R_NAME = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dgvc_R_NAME,
                Name = "R_NAME",
                HeaderText = "Name",
                MinimumWidth = 110,
                DataPropertyName = "NAME",
                DefaultCellStyle = otherCellStyle,
            };
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvTbxCol_R_NAME);

            DataGridViewCell dgvc_DATE = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvTbxCol_DATE = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = dgvc_DATE,
                Name = "DATE",
                HeaderText = "Date",
                MinimumWidth = 135,
                DataPropertyName = "DATE",
                DefaultCellStyle = otherCellStyle,
            };
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgvTbxCol_DATE);

            dgv.DataSource = recList;

            int dgvWidth = 0;
            int dgvHeight = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                if (dgvHeight == 0)
                {
                    normalRowHeight = row.Height;
                }
                dgvHeight += row.Height;
            }
            dgvWidth = pnlCust.Width - 17;
            dgv.Size = new Size(dgvWidth, dgvHeight);
            dgv.DataSource = recList;
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this, somewhere at top click a cell to select the contents, that should be fine.

If you go to the bottom, try to do the same I find it will not allow selection, I found at somewhere near row 1489 is where it stops working.
What could be causing this?

[EDIT2] 03 May 2017 8:00AM AU
The reason I place the DGV in the Panel is to get smooth scrolling. If I could get smooth scrolling on DGV I would just use that.

Comment: Instead of all theory, some code would certainly help

Comment: The `DataGridView`s Height = 32569?

Comment: The limit is considerably past the point where your user is still willing to talk to you.  The limit on the Height is a hard restriction in Windows, the mouse notification messages encode the X and Y mouse coordinate in a 16-bit value.  DGV can display a scrollbar by itself so this just isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks Han i understand however the case in which it will used is as a data auditing tool and a large grid will be fine. As far as just using the dgv itself, i tried that but i am going to have some rows that are a height of maybe up to several normal rows which means that when scrolling down it jumps when that row leaves the viewable area. The panel allows for smooth scrolling. I haven't come across a smooth scrolling dgv or if it is possible.

Comment: Use virtual mode in DataGridView.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, but if I just use the DGV by itself I'll need to make it smooth scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Datagridview.Rows.Count` returns an int value. So it can be maximum 2147483647

Comment: As Hans Passant written in the comment, the physical dimensions of all controls in Windows are limited to 16 bits.

Answer (score -2):

Very long DataGridViews are not useful.

My advice to you,

[0-1000] - [1000-2000] - .....

Using the buttons above.

Comment: That surely doesn't answer the question

Comment: Not an answer, a suggestion.

Comment: Chances are you will get a down-vote for not putting this in the comment